# VBA outputting text file data into excel with mapping table

Tags: vba, excel, text

I am trying to create a VBA script which will read Text Files which I have converted from PDF Files and pull out key information following search words.  All the Text Files will be located in a central location C:Work\Text

Within each of these Text Files is information that I would like to pull out and put into columns within Excel.  The search word helps identify the information but the search word may be different in each of the Text Files, so I will need to create a Table of search words.  And once it finds the information in one text file it can move onto the next one it doesn't need to post every instance of the search word appearing in the text file.

Example:
I am looking for Account Numbers and Amounts

Text File 1: Account Number can be found within the text file by Searching the word "Account Number:" and Amount can be found by searching "Amount:"

Account Number: 1234
Amount: $10

Text File 2: Account Number can be found within the text file by Searching the word "Account" and Amount can be found by searching "Cost"

Account 00090
Cost 25

Text File 3: Account Number can be found within the text file by Searching the word "Initial Number" and Amount can be found by searching "Total"

Initial Number 555555555
Total $90.02

Etc

So essential I would want to create a mapping table that references these Search Words and for it to just bring in the information after the search word .  If a new search word needs to be added I could always just add to the mapping table.

The output would essential put All the Account Number data into Column A1 and all the Amount Data will go into B1

Comment: So what's the problem? *Exactly* which part are you stuck on, what have you already tried, and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Hello Tim, I am very new to VBA so Ive only copied other pieces of code.  Below is the current code which converts PDF files into text then searches for key words in the PDF for a start and end strings and posts the information into a Output Sheet within Excel.  I am looking for a way to add multiple Key words rather than creating a new tab for the output.

Comment: The code can be found on http://www.business-spreadsheets.com/forum.asp?t=884 and it is the Run_Extraction() Macro

Comment: I am looking for a way to add multiple Key words (like a bunch of if statements referencing a list of key words within a Cell) rather than creating a new tab for each of the variations for the output.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote sample code to give pointers. You may need to iterate the same piece for rest. You may add multiple if conditions to search for the other patterns(just a suggestion)

```
Const ForReading = 1
Dim strSearchFor
dim i=1
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
‘Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xls")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add


For Each f In objFSO.GetFolder("C:\some\folder").Files
  Set objFile = f.OpenAsTextStream
  strSearchFor = "Account Number"
  Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    'do stuff with strLine and append to strText
    If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor) <> 0 then
        Wscript.Echo "Account Number found"
        objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value = strLine
        i=i+1
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "Account Number not found"
    End If
  Loop
  objFile.Close

Next

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\test.xls"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
```

Comment: Hello Raju thank you for posting this I will test it out i'm very new to VBA so it may take me some time and trial and error.  I know I was looking for a way to reference a list of Key words from a List within the Excel doc rather than hardcoding the key words in the VBA code.

Comment: @JustinStaugaitis, did you fix your issue??

Comment: I need some time to pick this back up I dont want to lose your post though.  Thank you